# What does them refer to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Jess Huang: This is a big, trending topic for companies. Predictive analytics can definitely help you refine and fine-tune the design of your loyalty program. It helps you better understand your different types of consumers, how much they’re spending, and how valuable they are to you. So it allows you to start thinking about how to migrate them up in value and decide which ones you are willing to spend more on.

Source: https://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/marketing-and-sales/our-insights/customer-loyalty-the-new-generation?cid=soc-app

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the types of customers. The same groups that were referred to by "they" twice in the previous sentence.

Comment: I think you meant to say "types of consumers", which is the phrase that actually appears in the quotation.